# jsTree (3.x) ajax config handlers runs only once?

Tags: javascript, jstree

I read the [documentation](http://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=$.jstree.defaults.core.data) about how to setup ajax data source to jsTree component. But I really don't understand following code:

```
        'data': {
            'url': function (node) {
                return '/ajax/test-nodes';
            },
            'data': function (node) {
                return {'id': node.id};
            }
        }
```

1) Why I need to use function for 'url', how advantages it gives?

2) Why 'url' and 'data' handlers runs only one time(I use console.log to check it), despite to my ajax response contains many nodes:

```
[{"id":1,"parent":"#","text":"n1"},{"id":2,"parent":"#","text":"n2"},{"id":3,"parent":"1","text":"child of n1"},{"id":4,"parent":"1","text":"child of n1"},{"id":5,"parent":"3","text":"subChild of n1"}]
```

3) What value I need to return from this functions ('url', 'data') ?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty clear in the [docs of the config option](http://www.jstree.com/api/#/?q=core.data&f=$.jstree.defaults.core.data):

> In addition to the standard jQuery ajax options here you can suppy functions for data and url, the functions will be run in the current instance's scope and a param will be passed indicating which node is being loaded, the return value of those functions will be used.

It is also explained here [in the repository](https://github.com/vakata/jstree#populating-the-tree-using-ajax-and-lazy-loading-nodes):

> First off the `data` config option of the `core.data` object. If you check with jQuery, it is supposed to be a string or an object. But jstree makes it possible to set a function. Each time jstree needs to make an AJAX call this function will be called and will receive a single parameter - the node that is being loaded. The return value of this function will be used as the actual "data" of the AJAX call. To understand better open up the demo and see the requests go off in the console.
>
> ...
>
> You can also set `url` to a function and it works exactly as with `data` - each time a request has to be made, jstree will invoke your function and the request will go off to whatever you return in this function. This is useful when dealing with URLs like: `http://example.com/get_children/1`

Read the above links to get familiar with what lazy loading is and how to use it - there are also many examples.